# How to find a unit vector normal to a plane containing Vectors A & B

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Vectors A and B are given. The solution provided by the professor says this is the answer:
$\frac{\vec{A}*\vec{B}}{|\vec{A}||\vec{B}|}$
I did a bit of Googling and various website says this is the correct way to find the unit vector normal to a plane:
$\frac{\vec{A}*\vec{B}}{|\vec{A}X\vec{B}|}$
Which one is correct?

Comment: Is this for an arbitrary pair of vectors or are they perpendicular to each other?

Comment: @amd Arbitrary pair of vectors, but applying the dot product shows that they are not perpendicular.

Comment: @Juan Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- substitute in some vectors and you can figure out which one is wrong isn't it.
- Note that for $u \ne 0$, $\|\frac{u}{\|u\|}\|=1$
- Note that for cross product, $\|u \times v\| =\|u\|\|v\|\sin \theta $

Comment: Using vectors <3,0> and <3,4>. For method 1, I get z/15. Method 2, I get z.

Comment: so  the one that doesn't give you a unit vector must be wrong right? are you in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: So Method 2 is correct. What is R3?

Comment: $3$ dimensional space. Well, we have ruled out method $1$, and the reason second method is correct is due to $\|\frac{u}{\|u\|}\|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

By cross product, it is equal to

$$\vec n=\frac{\vec{A}\times\vec{B}}{|\vec{A}||\vec{B}|\sin \theta}$$